# objective c swipe to delete in table view

Tags: objective-c, swipe

I have two custom cells. I'm trying to make swipe to delete button. 
But it crashes when I click delete button.

Here is the code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        if (indexPath.row % 2 == 0) {
            [_arrayCars removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row/2];
            [_tblCars deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        }else{
            [_arrayGirls removeObjectAtIndex:(indexPath.row - 1)/2];
            [_tblCars deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        }
        withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Unhandled editing style! %d", editingStyle);
    }
}
```

Here is what I get:

```
    ExampleXib[6957:281486] -[__NSArrayI removeObjectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7feea851bc60
    2017-01-23 19:31:49.798 ExampleXib[6957:281486] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI removeObjectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7feea851bc60'
```

Comment: _arrayCars is Immutable array, and you cant delete objects in it. Make it mutable and it should be fine!

Comment: Is `_arrayCars` declared as `NSArray`? If YES, declare (and do the correct alloc/init) as `NSMutableArray`. If it's already declared as a `NSMutableArray`, please check where you create it, and do `[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:tempArray]` if needed, because `tempArray` was a `NSArray`, and you did `_arrayCars = tempArray;`, could cause the issue.

Comment: thanx, it worked fine with "initWithArray"!